# Importing URL images in Java from a protected website

Tags: java

I was trying to import a picture from a website and when you load the site for the first time there is some kind of rerouting server that lets only browsers in.
I tried this:

```
public class TestURLImage {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            try {
                String path = "https://kissanime.to/Uploads/Etc/12-15-2012/726336142483.jpg";
                System.out.println("Geting Image from " + path);
                System.out.println();    
                URL url = new URL(path);
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
                System.out.println("Loading image into frame...");
                JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.getContentPane().add(label);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocation(200, 200);
                f.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

}}
```

But I get an error:

```
Geting Image from https://kissanime.to/Uploads/Etc/12-15-2012/726336142483.jpg    

javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1395)
at javaapplication6.TestURLImage$1.run(TestURLImage.java:35)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://kissanime.to/Uploads/Etc/12-15-2012/726336142483.jpg
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1393)
... 15 more
```

So is there some kind of way to get the image ?
Or at least what is the problem?

Comment: The URL directs you to a html page first, which then seems to use a http `get` to post a `form` which retrieves the actual asset. I was able to get this by using Apache's Http-Client and spoofing the browser agent, which didn't seem to work when I tried doing the same thing with `URL` (but I hardly tried).  The idea would be to download the html content, strip out the `<form>` element and use a http `get` to submit the `form` properties manually

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use something more advanced like [apache HTTP Client library](https://hc.apache.org/). You will have much more control on all the communication. For instance you could set a standard user agent to fake a normal request.

Comment: So after digging arround i found that it is looking for a javascript enabled browser so could it emulate javascript for an IoInputStream